# Long wait time on page load

Tags: php, css, performance, iis-8, pagespeed

i've done minifying all the js/css file, compressing all images for that page, prevent render  blocking by moving to the bottom before closing of body and even removing all the js to test load but it still take more than 40 seconds to load the index php page.

there's no issue when it's on my local machine (iis 7.5) my host is running on iis 8 ... i've tried uploding to another server on cpanel(linux) platform and there's no issue.

web.config

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <configuration>
      <system.webServer>
        <caching enabled="true" enableKernelCache="true" maxCacheSize="1000" maxResponseSize="512000">
          <profiles>
            <add extension=".php" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" />
            <add extension=".js" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" />
            <add extension=".css" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" />
            <add extension=".gif" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" />
            <add extension=".jpg" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" />
          </profiles>
        </caching>
        <httpProtocol>
          <customHeaders>
            <remove name="Vary"></remove>
            <add name="Vary" value="Accept-Encoding"></add>
          </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
        <staticContent>
          <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache" />
        </staticContent>
        <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="false" />
        <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="index.html" />
                <add value="index.asp" />
                <add value="index.aspx" />
                <add value="index.php" />
                <add value="default.php" />
                <add value="default.html" />
                <add value="Default.htm" />
                <add value="Default.asp" />
                <add value="index.htm" />
                <add value="Default.aspx" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" existingResponse="Auto" />
        <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
            <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll"/>
            <dynamicTypes>
                <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
                <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
                <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
                <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
            </dynamicTypes>
            <staticTypes>
                <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
                <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
                <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
                <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
            </staticTypes>
        </httpCompression>
      </system.webServer>
      <system.web>
          <sessionState mode="Off" />
      </system.web>
  </configuration>
```

analyzed the site with pingdom and below's the result for [my Site](http://sausenglum.com.my/demo2016/)

[image][image]

Comment: Seems like TTFB is high. Might be a problem in PHP. Can you reproduce the problem on your local development environment?

Comment: nop.. my local development environment (iis 7.5) is running on the same set of files but not having this issue

Comment: If you make any database queries, they might be the cause. Furthermore, I'd try and introduce `error_log` statements with PID, file, line and time running to diagnose your problem.

Comment: thanks Daan, i'll do that